# Creating new variable using information from multiple lines in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"HouseholdNumber": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], "TypeOfPerson": ["Son", "Daughter", "Daughter", "Parent", "Parent", "Daughter", "Parent"], "Age": [17, 10, 20, 52, 45, 22, 50]})
print(df)
   HouseholdNumber TypeOfPerson  Age
0                1          Son   17   
1                1     Daughter   10   
2                1     Daughter   20  
3                1       Parent   52     
4                1       Parent   45    
5                2     Daughter   22    
6                2       Parent   50
```

and I want to create a new variable using information from multiple lines. This is a problem for me because I'm having problems with using a simple `df.loc` (or `np.where`) condition. Specifically, I want the new variable to have the value `no` in case the person is not a parent or has no child in the age groups, an `a` if the parent has a child which is 18 years old or younger and a `b` if the parent has a child which is between 19 and 25 years old. If the parents have a child of both age groups, the value should still be an `a`. The HouseholdNumber indicates the different families, so all the conditions should apply for each Household. So, the dataframe should look like this:

```
   HouseholdNumber TypeOfPerson  Age Child
0                1          Son   17    no
1                1     Daughter   10    no
2                1     Daughter   20    no
3                1       Parent   52     a
4                1       Parent   45     a
5                2     Daughter   22    no
6                2       Parent   50     b
```

The code I'm trying is

```
df["Child"]=""
for i in df["HouseholdNumber"].unique():
    if (df.loc[df.TypeOfPerson.isin(["Son", "Daughter"]) & (df.Age <= 18)]):
       if (df.loc[(df.TypeOfPerson == "Parent")]):
           df["Child"] = "a"
    elif (df.loc[df.TypeOfPerson.isin(["Son", "Daughter"]) & ((df.Age >= 19) & (df.Age <= 26))]):
       df["Child"] = "b"
    else:
        df["Child"] = "no"
```

which gives me the error `The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`. I'm not really sure where to go from here, I always get this error. Even without the error I suspect that my code will not give the desired result though.

Comment: How do you determine which child belongs to which `Parent`?

Comment: By having the same HouseholdNumber, meaning that I always have the simple case that all the children belong to all parents in one household

Answer (score 1):

The error here, is that you accessing `df.loc` with a list of indices, for example:

```
 df.loc[df.TypeOfPerson.isin(["Son", "Daughter"]) & (df.Age <= 18)]
```

would return a dataframe with several rows. So when you put it behind an `if` it asks how to evaluate that dataframe as a boolean, would it be `any` of the cells `True` or `all` of the cells `True`, etc.

One way to fix the error is to specify the said operation, or in your case, you wanted to know if the house has any children, you can simply check the length of the sliced dataframe:

```
for i in df["HouseholdNumber"].unique():
    # you didn't use this i in your code
    ppl_in_house = (df.HouseholdNumber == i)
    is_child = df.TypeOfPerson.isin(["Son", "Daughter"])

    num_children = sum(ppl_in_house & is_child)
```

Of course that is just one way to solve your problem, not the best way.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `groupby` for something like this, since you can deal with each household at once

Example (note that not all cases are handled)

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "TypeOfPerson": ["Son", "Parent", "Daughter", "Son", "Parent", "Daughter", "Daughter", "Parent", "Son"],
    "HouseholdNumber": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "Age": [17,50,20,13,40,19,5, 50, 25]
})

# Add new column
df["Child"] = pd.Series()

# Group by household
households = df.groupby("HouseholdNumber")

# Iterate through groups
for household_number in households.groups:
    household = households.get_group(household_number)

    # Household offspring
    offspring = household.query("TypeOfPerson == 'Son' | TypeOfPerson == 'Daughter'")

    # Sons and daughters that are 18 or younger
    children = offspring.query("Age <= 18")

    # Sons and daughters that young adults (19 >= age <= 25)
    young_adults = household.query("Age >= 19 & Age <= 25")

    # Parents
    parents = household.query("TypeOfPerson == 'Parent'")

    # Change original data frame
    df.loc[offspring.index, "Child"] = "No"
    if children.shape[0]:
        df.loc[parents.index, "Child"] = "a" 
    elif young_adults.shape[0]:
         df.loc[parents.index, "Child"] = "b"
```